# Hashicorp Vault encrypt data

Tags: java, spring, hashicorp-vault, spring-vault

Can `Hashicorp Vault` encrypt data?
I'm using the Vault as the key(s) storage for now, but does vault able to encrypt data for the application?

**Scenario**:
My client is a java application, accessing Vault through Vault's Java spring API. Will java be able to send a big/long string to Vault and receive the encrypted version of that string? In another word using Vault as an encryptor and decryptor service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Vault can act as [Encryption as a Service](https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/encryption-as-a-service/eaas-transit)

You will need to enable transit sercrets engine, create a keyring and encrypt/decrypt your data:

```
vault secrets enable transit
vault write -f transit/keys/orders
vault write transit/encrypt/orders plaintext=$(base64 <<< "4111 1111 1111 1111")
vault write transit/decrypt/orders \
    ciphertext="vault:v1:cZNHVx+sxdMErXRSuDa1q/pz49fXTn1PScKfhf+PIZPvy8xKfkytpwKcbC0fF2U=" \
```

Read more [here](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/transit/index.html) and [api](https://www.vaultproject.io/api/secret/transit/index.html)